# "had already gone" vs "had already left"

Tags: past-perfect

Is there any difference?

> Did you meet her yeasterday? - I was late. When I came the train had
>   already gone/left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slight nuanced difference might be

> the train had already **left**.

implies a short time ago

> I just missed the train, it had just **left**.

Whereas

> the train had already **gone**.

might mean you missed the train by a greater amount of time than "**left**".

Both mean you were

[image]